# Ng-model is not working as expected?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, model-view-controller, angular-ngmodel

I have a textbox which is connected to angular js with `ng-model=sampleValue`

Now, my requirement is whenever I click on the button show function should be executed and the textbox's value should be changed to Harish. But this is not the result I'm getting. Please take a look at the code that I have written below:

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", [])

app.controller("mainController", [ "$scope", function($scope){
  $scope.show = function(){
    $scope.sampleValue = "Harish";
  }
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app = "myApp">
<input ng-controller="mainController" type="text" ng-model="sampleValue"/>
<button ng-click="show()">Click Here</button>
</body>
```

Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently you had applied `ng-controller` over input element, which means controller scope has restricted on `input` DOM only, because of which `show` method would not get call. You should move `ng-controller` to wrapper element(here its `body`).

```
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js">  </script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="mainController">

  <input type="text" ng-model="sampleValue" />
  <button ng-click="show()">Click Here</button>
</body>
```

[**Plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/QEYSnkhK32uOk5HdYg0b?p=preview)

Answer (score 2):

Move ng-controller to body tag:

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", [])

app.controller("mainController", [ "$scope", function($scope){
  $scope.show = function(){
    $scope.sampleValue = "Harish";
  }
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app = "myApp"  ng-controller="mainController">
<input type="text" ng-model="sampleValue"/>
<button ng-click="show()">Click Here</button>
</body>
```

Comment: This is working but what is the difference in placing the controller in body tag and in an element which is inside the body tag ?? Both should be the same I guess??

Comment: ng controller must be before ng model because model variable or say scope is under the controller

Answer (score 1):

Put `ng-controller` in body or in some parent `div`. You are using `ng-controller` in `input type`

Try this

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">

<head>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.1/angular.js"></script>
 
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">

  angular.module('myApp',[])
  .controller('myCtrl', function myCtrl($scope,$filter) {


   $scope.showValue = function(){
    $scope.sampleValue = "Harish";
   }
  })



 </script>

</head>

<body ng-controller="myCtrl">
 <input type="text" ng-model="sampleValue"/>
 <button ng-click="showValue()">Click Here</button>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks. But what is the difference in placing the controller in the parent tag??

Comment: If you will put controller in parent tag then it will be available in all child tags, then only you will be able to access `controller` from view, or will be able to call any function.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", [])

app.controller("mainController", [ "$scope", function($scope){
  $scope.show = function(){
    $scope.sampleValue = "Harish";
  }
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app = "myApp" ng-controller="mainController">
<input  type="text" ng-model="sampleValue"/>
<button ng-click="show()">Click Here</button>
</body>
```

your ng-controller is on the input

Answer (score 1):

The fact is you used ng-controller over input tag. so outside of the input tag inside controller function will not work. your js is totally ok. u just need to change the html

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <body ng-app = "myApp" >
    <input  type="text" ng-model="sampleValue"/>
    <button ng-click="show()">Click Here</button>
    </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    <title>Ang</title>
</head>
<body>
<div ng-app="">
  <h1>Ng-show  ng-hide</h1>
  <p class="description">Click on the "show"-link to see the content.</p>
  <a href="" ng-click="showme=true">Show</a>
  <button ng-click="showme=false">Hide</button> 

  <div class="wrapper">
    <p ng-hide="showme">It will appear here!</p>
    <h2 ng-show="showme">This is mah content, yo!</h2>
  </div>

</div>    

</body>
</html>
```

Try executing the above code you may get an idea for you code.

Answer (score 0):

Your controller scope is limited to input text box.

```
   <body ng-app = "myApp">
      <div ng-controller="mainController">
      <input  type="text" ng-model="sampleValue"/>
      <button ng-click="show()">Click Here</button>
      </div>
   </body>
```